Convolutional Filters that detect number of ones in binary matrix
I am studying a deep learning course and one of the questions in the course is like a puzzle game:
Part (a)
Given a 4 by 4 binary matrix (consisting only zeros and ones), design a CNN that can detect exactly 7 ones in the matrix with the following constriants:

at most 3 layers, conv or pooling
use only 2x2 filters with stride 1, no padding
use a threshold function at the last layer, with output = 1 if (x dot w) >= threshold, 0 otherwise. x is the output from the last layer of the networks, and w is a vector you can define in any real numbers. All activations in the intermediate layers are identity functions

Specify the weights in each filter of each layer, any bias, vector w, and threshold.
The network should output 1 if there are exactly 7 ones, 0 otherwise.
Part (b)
Try to provide a CNN with the above constraints but can detect the digit 7:
1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
If not possible, provide a reason.
Part (c)
Try to provide a CNN with the above constraints but can detect at most 7 ones in a 4 by 4 binary matrix. If not possible, provide a reason.
Solving any 1 part is appreciated!
